# Exporing InDesign as PDF with Copiable Text

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I can't figure this one out. I want to export an InDesign file (1 page) as an interactive PDF. I also want the receive to be able to highlight and copy text, however. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

A typical PDF coming out of InDesign with interactivity will, by default, have highlightable and copyable text - nothing special needed.

Comment: It hasn't though.